# How do I use the `data-text` attribute in an img element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the `data-text` attribute of html to assign text to an image, and then use the jQuery to pull the text from that image use it to alter a span element somewhere else. Does `data-text` work? It does not seem to be working on my code. Are there any alternatives?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
var target = $(".flex-active-slide img").attr("data-text");
$("#video_box_label").html(target);
```

Here is the html with the data-text attribute:

```
<li id="Abijah_Ayele_slide">
    <img id="Abijah_Ayele_image" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_People/Abijah_Ayele.jpg" data-text="Abijah_Ayele">    
</li>
<li id="slide2">
    <img id="slide_image_2" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_People/Adil_Saleem.jpg" data-text="Adil_Saleem">
</li>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, aside from the fact that you have two `img` elements, so `attr()` would only read the attribute from the first one. You probably need a loop. Do you have a specific issue with the code?

Comment: `.flex-active-slide` doesn't exist in your markup.  You're example appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Why don't you use alt attribute? It is important to have it with your image and you can easily get it using $("img").attr("alt");

Answer (score 1):

`data-text` is not an attribute with any special functionality. Attributes starting with `data-` prefix are custom attributes as [w3schools says](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). You can use [jQuery `.data()` function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to manipulate this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `data-` to many tags including `<img>`

It could be any text after the `data-` part (in your case you are using "text", but it could respectively be `data-othertext` or `data-thirdtext` - just reference it correctly later on (see below)).

You are using: `<img id="slide_image_2" src="Adil_Saleem.jpg" data-text="Adil_Saleem">`

In jquery you can access the `data-` like so:

```
$('#slide_image_2').data('text');
```

Put it in a var like so:

```
var dataText = $('#slide_image_2').data('text');
```

Now `dataText` value is `Adil_Saleem`.

And you could then manipulate data as you require. 
If you are looking to add it as html of a `<span>`, it may look like:

HTML: `<span id="myspan"></span>`

jQuery: `$("#myspan").html(dataText);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){ 
  var $t = $(this);

  console.log($t.attr('data-text'));

  // Or if you want to append it to an element you already have 
  $('element').html($t.attr('data-text'));
}
```

Comment: or `$t.data('text')` since we're using jQuery anyway

Comment: To play it safe, .attr() is a good option. The older jQuery lib don't support .data()